Function not outputting value
Good Day
I have created a function in VBA which checks the salary input is between two bands and if so then must do a calculation. I have taken the code out of the function and it works exactly how it should however in the function it does not return the result and not sure what is the cause of it. Do I need to add in the return method in the function?
The code is below:
Function TaxTableCalculation(Salary) As Long
If TaxIncomeLowBand_1 < Salary And Salary <= TaxIncomeHighBand_1 Then

        TaxTableCalculation = (Salary - TaxIncomeLowBand_1) * PercentageTaxBand_1 + BaseTaxBand_1

ElseIf TaxIncomeLowBand_2 < Salary And Salary <= TaxIncomeHighBand_2 Then

        TaxTableCalculation = (Salary - TaxIncomeLowBand_2) * PercentageTaxBand_2 + BaseTaxBand_2
        
ElseIf TaxIncomeLowBand_3 < Salary And Salary <= TaxIncomeHighBand_3 Then

        TaxTableCalculation = (Salary - TaxIncomeLowBand_3) * PercentageTaxBand_3 + BaseTaxBand_3

    End If
End Function

Dim Salary As String

Salary = InputBox("Input your salary,no decimals only whole numbers")

'TaxCalcOutput = TaxTableCalculation(Salary)

Any advice or assistnce will be greatly appreciated

For starters, are you really comparing a string to your salary bands (which I'm assuming are not actually strings)?

Function TaxTableCalculation(Salary As Single) As Long but make sure what you pass it is numeric. Also, depending on what output you expect, you may want to use Single instead of Long for the function's type.

if the salary does not lie within any of your taxincomebands you would get the result you are experiencing.

Where do you expect to see the output? If you put the lines after End Function within a Sub, and uncomment the TaxCalcOutput line, your function returns 0 to TaxCalcOutput, as expected since none of your bands are defined in your code.

@Michal Rosa thank you for pointing that out and I have changed the data type however the output still did not come through

@Ron Rosenfeld I have defined my bands in the code, I have just omitted it out of the one I have posted

@Rehaan As I wrote, given your code, it returns the expected value to the variable. Why post working code if your problem is with different code which is not working?

Dim Salary As Double

You have to force the correct variable type for your Salary

If this is the only change, you will get an error if you enter a non-numeric value, so the user input would probably need to also be checked afterwards to make sure it's numeric.

The question was not about writing a whole blown validation framework. This might be a simple POC task, and hence the response
